# Вставка компонента в html c сервера

Tags: javascript, vue.js

С сервера приходит строка такого вида '

## Description + pictures

[slideshow:1]

' нужно вместо [slideshow:1] подставить компонент слайдера.

Конечно же поиск элемента в DOM удаление и вставка нового содержимого не помогла, то есть как, слайдер то вставился, но он скорее мёртв чем жив :)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на пакет [v-runtime-template](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template)